# Suggestions for switching 800VDC converter on/off

Tags: relay, timer, converter, test

I'm stress testing(turning them on-off with load every 300 seconds for 1-2 weeks) the components that we are willing to use. have tested several battery chargers with AC input with using a timer relay like this:

[image]

My question is what would be the best way of stress testing a DC/DC converter which has input of 800V DC? ([This one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/2866530/277-12079-ND/4484286))

Comment: MOSFET SSR. 800 V is beyond the capability of most.

Comment: @winny thank you for the input, which specs should I pay attention for selecting the right mosfet?

Comment: If you need to ask, aim at buying a ready-made SSR.

Comment: IGBT are available for 1200V as standard.

Comment: @Marko OP should be very aware of cable/loop/source/device inductance. Without snubber and/or sufficient avalanche rating, a 1200 V device can be toasted on the first turn-off.

Comment: @winny But he needs a gate driver board first, which is not easy to find. Then it has to put some fast freewheeling diode, snubber,...AVAGO offered a very neat and cheap board ACPL-P349/W349, but they are gone when Broadcom aquired them.

Comment: @Marko Broadcom stopped manufacturing their excellent RF schottkys when Avago aquired them...  Well, OP is better off finding a good commercial SSR. I foresee they stop at 600 V and he will have to connect two in series, time them very carefully and have a daddy-sized RC snubber across each.

Comment: @winny AC SSR plenty of them, DC SSR you won't find easy.

Comment: @Marko Exactly!

Comment: The best test plan uses the product specs to verify at elevated temperature and various loads.  Power cycling should be on both input measuring inrush current and output for stability.  A 1kV relay can handle the input and any dummy loads with MOSFET switches for an active load with the measurement system.